# how to count number of unique (by 3rd field in a whole set) ids by type

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling to solve the following problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6a22/13

I have a data set:

```
| ID | NAME | TYPE | ACC_FK |                              TS |
|----|------|------|--------|---------------------------------|
|  1 |  qwe |    3 |    123 | November, 19 2013 00:43:33+0000 |
|  2 |  asd |    3 |    234 | November, 19 2013 00:43:33+0000 |
|  3 |  zxc |    2 |    123 | November, 19 2013 00:43:33+0000 |
|  4 |  wer |    2 |    345 | November, 19 2013 00:43:33+0000 |
```

I need to count number of unique (by acc_fk in a whole set) ids by type. So the result should be based on the following data set (excluding either 'zxc' or 'qwe'), e.g.:

```
| ID | NAME | TYPE | ACC_FK |                              TS |
|----|------|------|--------|---------------------------------|
|  1 |  qwe |    3 |    123 | November, 19 2013 00:43:33+0000 |
|  2 |  asd |    3 |    234 | November, 19 2013 00:43:33+0000 |
|  4 |  wer |    2 |    345 | November, 19 2013 00:43:33+0000 |
```

"unique by acc_fk in a whole set" means that I don't want to count the same acc_fk twice in any group of type. And the result of the query should be:

```
+------------------+
| Type | COUNT(id) |
+------+-----------+
|  2   |    1      |
|  3   |    2      |
+------------------+
```

So for the type 2 I wanna see 'wer', for type 3 I wanna see: 'qwe' and 'asd'.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what "unique (by acc_fk in a whole set) ids by type" means. Can you clarify?

Comment: Can you confirm that your expectations are correct? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6a22/26

Comment: It is clear that there are only 3 different acc_fk in the whole table. Now, why are you counting one of them for type 2 and two of them for trype 3? Why not the other way around?

Comment: You're right, other way would be ok also. I've updated question. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [@Mosty Mostacho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061274/how-to-count-number-of-unique-by-3rd-field-in-a-whole-set-ids-by-type/20061486#comment29882690_20061274):

  > It is clear that there are only 3 different acc_fk in the whole table. Now, why are you counting one of them for type 2 and two of them for trype 3? Why not the other way around?
- [@Horoshiy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061274/how-to-count-number-of-unique-by-3rd-field-in-a-whole-set-ids-by-type/20061486#comment29882700_20061274):

  > You're right, other way would be ok also. I've updated question. Makes sense?

This is a very strange problem, as it leads to indeterminate results.

```
SELECT   type, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT acc_fk, type FROM t1 GROUP BY acc_fk) t
GROUP BY type
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6a22/28/0).

Comment: great, it works. I understand that values for rows are undeterminate, but counts are correct. Thanks a bunch!